# Can local devices connect to my router through the WAN port?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I live in an apartment complex that supplies internet connectivity from a third-party provider. For a host of reasons, I opted to connect my own router into the connection coming out of the wall instead of using their supplied switch and wifi access points. This was all fine and good for about a year when they decided to call and tell me to take the router off the network as it's against their policy.

After responding and getting no response for a month, I finally got another call today asking me to take it down. When I asked why it had gotten on their radar, they said that it was "assigning IPs to other tenants and causing them issues with connecting to the internet".

So, I had to confirm this when I got home, but I definitely have the "internet supplying" ethernet cable connected into my WAN port and not a LAN port. My understanding is that, yes, if I had attached my router to to the network from a LAN port, something like that could potentially happen, but is there any possible way that what they've described could happen when my router is simply using their connection as a "dumb" internet connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How was my wireless router detected by my internet provider and can I prevent it?](http://superuser.com/questions/978258/how-was-my-wireless-router-detected-by-my-internet-provider-and-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: What subnet is the building using and does it overlap with your local DHCP? They might be doing building wide NAT.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, your router firmware could be buggy and serving out DHCP leases on the WAN port. Or it could be that someone else's device was causing the problems, but when the sysadmins ran some tool looking for unauthorized routers, they found yours and figured yours could be (part of) the problem.

You could plug in a port-mirroring-capable switch between the wall and the WAN port of your router, and run a sniffer looking at what traffic your router is sending out its WAN port.

Comment: Can you recommend a reasonably priced switch for this purpose? Or assuming this isn't what's happening (and I'm just taking the fall for someone else's device), is there any way to conceal the router's existence on the wired network? I've already hidden the wireless SSID.

Comment: @noisetank D-Link DGS-1100-05 5-port Gigabit switch for US$36 claims to do port mirroring. I haven't used it, so can't vouch for it.